# Sharing internet connection from WiFi to Thunderbolt Ethernet doesn't work - no DHCP addresses are given out

Tags: network, ethernet, internet-sharing

I can't seem to get my MacBook Pro to share the WiFi connection over Ethernet. Here is my configuration as it appears in System Preferences:

> [image: Internet Sharing settings]
>   [image: Network settings]

As you can see, my local Ethernet IP address is a self-assigned IP and the connected device does not receive an IP address.

I see the following messages in my Console when I try to enable Internet Sharing:

```
2/18/16 4:40:11.421 PM InternetSharing[9126]: missing dhcp parameters: start address 10.168.2.0, end address  or mask 
2/18/16 4:40:11.422 PM configd[60]: sharing service over en5 failed
```

Clearly I have a misconfiguration somewhere. How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of System Preferences>Network when Wi-Fi is selected and the output of `netstat -rn -f inet`? I'm trying to understand why Internet Sharing complains about missing DHCP parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this by manually configuring the address of the MacBook Ethernet port as 192.168.2.1 and manually configuring the device I attached to connect to 192.168.2.1.